Should I upgrade my camera body or lens for low-light indoors sports photography?
Again the much debated topic, but this time it gets a bit more interesting.
I have a Nikon D3300 with a AF-S 50 mm f/1.8 which I really like. However I find myself doing inside volleyball sport photography a lot lately which presents me with the following problem: the camera has a hard time locking focus. When it does, the pictures are really good and I can crop in a ton. I use f/1.8 1/500s and ISO 1000.
In order to improve on this, I would like to have a newer body, namely a D750 and not APS-C anymore for lighting and AF reasons. However then I would have to crop in a lot more reducing quality which is bad; and also, would the missing crop factor make it more difficult for the AF?
The other option is a used Tamron 70–200 mm f/2.8 which is practically equal price wise.
In my mind being closer to the object would make it easier for the AF and thus better AF performance? However, I lose low light capabilities since it is f/2.8 instead of f/1.8 which I need because the gyms are pretty dim I think.
What would be the best thing to do and why, especially if you could only buy one?

While not the same subjects, this question is possible a dupe of (or at least very related to) one of my questions: Would a different body help me with noise reduction?

There is also How to photograph low light indoor sport? which is about shooting volleyball!

@PeterM i have read that post and while it gives valuable info on indoor action photography, it does not make things clearer for my particular question.

@PeterM i am also more interested in the combination of composition (50 mm on FF even further away compared to apsc) and af (my d3300 struggles to lock AF while d750 has a superb AF system I hear). My question was if an appropriate zoom lens (70-200 2.8) gives me more advantage in AF due to beeing closer than the AF system of the d750 on 50 mm

If you're cropping, sensor size makes no difference. It's pixel density that gives you more "reach". Typically APS-C sensors have smaller sensels so they can put more pixels on your target with the same focal length. For Nikon, a FF sensor needs 2.25X as many MP to have the same pixel density as an APS-C body. Your 24MP D3300 has the same pixel density as a 54MP FF camera would.

Just FYI, the high ISO noise performance between a D750 and D3300 may not be as much as you're assuming. It's more like one stop (D3300 at 3200 vs. D750 at 6400), since they're both mostly the same age. Newer crop sensors can give you a similar advantage.

The D750 has pretty good and reliable autofocus, but one problem with it is coverage: the D810/D850 cover a bigger part of the frame, and the autofocus systems on APS-C cameras tend to cover more.  3D tracking does not work when the subject leaves the covered area.
For sports usage, the APS-C size D500 comes with high acclaims, its autofocus coverage is large, fast and accurate and it does high ISO well.  With either sensor size, a 70-200mm/2.8 would let you go places.

Don't replace either until you've learned how to use one of the modern miracles known as recent noise reduction apps so you can trust whatever camera you use to shoot at ISO 3200 or higher. Limiting yourself to ISO 1000 for sports in an indoor gym will lead to massive frustration no matter what camera body and lens you use.
Even without cutting edge noise reduction, what comes out of the camera when you shoot in less than optimal conditions doesn't have to be what the finished image looks like.
Lots of noise in my hockey pictures. What am I doing wrong?
Also be sure you're doing everything you can to get the most out of what you already have.
How to improve image sharpness on Canon 700D? The linked answer applies to any camera and lens.
Then critically analyze what you'd like to improve, where your gear is holding you back in that regard, and find a technological solution that meets that need. The case study at the end of this answer to When should I upgrade my camera body? illustrates this.

Paying subscription and wasting time in 3rd party tools just to remove noise is not a better idea than replacing a relic of a consumable (camera) with something that can deal with those issues

Not all NR applications are by subscription. I use no subscription software (including Adobe products). There has been no significant improvement of sensors with regard to low light/high ISO performance in about a decade.

@CristiBăluță Aside from many products not being subscription based, pretty well all of them offer a free evaluation period.  I had some photos that needed noise reduction and spent an afternoon downloading and evaluating several products.  After which I slapped down my credit card and said "Sell me your product!!!!"  from only one vender.  And I spent well less than 1/20 of what it would cost to upgrade my hardware.

I can't really make a blanket recommendation on specific gear, but I can offer a couple of things to consider that might help.

50mm is a very short lens for sports, even with the APC crop factor (I usually shoot anywhere from 150-400 when I shoot sports)
With a longer lens and a larger aperture (facilitated by a higher ISO) you might find that the AF is a lot more forgiving because your depth of field will be a lot wider
Higher noise will be less noticeable if you're not cropping in nearly as far
The lens you're looking at does have its own internal focusing motor that is reportedly very fast. (I don't own one so can't confirm personally)
The sweet spot for focus on most lenses is slightly higher than their minimum aperture. (My 50mm f1.8 gets a little soft at f1.8, but performs much better at f2)
It might also depend on what your other use cases are.
Let's be honest with ourselves... it's probably not going to be or so much as which first


Outdoors, field sports can use 150-400mm very effectively. Indoors that's almost always too long, even on a FF sensor. 70-200/2.8 is the workhorse in a gym. 85/135/200mm for the primes. Plus a wide angle 24mm or wider on FF; 16mm or wider on APS-C if you're shooting right under the baseline (basketball) or from side court (volleyball). Even in a newer type high school "arena" type gym, I found that my 120-300mm f/2.8 was too long shooting from behind the end line on the walkway that goes around the top of the stands (almost a full court length behind the back line).

Not to mention that 150-400mm zoom lenses are usually way too slow to effectively shoot indoors sports or field sports under lights at night. Those are daylight lenses as far as sports are concerned.

@MichaelC to be clear, that 150-400 spans 3 lenses for different situations. I also use a 70-200 f2.8 when shooting indoors, but I tend to live at the extreme end of it. But I also usually am not court side, I'm generally a bit further away.
